# How to avoid overriding of signal handlers in Python?

Tags: python, signals

My experiment code is like:

```
import signal

def hi(signum, frame):
    print "hi"

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, hi)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

`hi` didn't get printed, because the signal handler is overridden by `signal.SIG_IGN`.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to check whether there is already a handler. If so put your desired handler and the old handler in a wrapper function that calls both of them.

```
def append_signal(sig, f):

    old = None
    if callable(signal.getsignal(sig)):
        old = signal.getsignal(sig)

    def helper(*args, **kwargs):
        if old is not None:
            old(*args, **kwargs)
        f(*args, **kwargs)

    signal.signal(sig, helper)
```

Comment: If there's a built-in default handler for the signal like `signal.default_int_handler`, this would fail because `signal.default_int_handler` raises `KeyboardInterrupt` and newly appended handlers won't get executed.

Comment: The solution for that would be to catch all exceptions from the handlers and print the error somewhere. (That's what I have seen in similar scenarios). Would that be a problem in your case?

Comment: just call yours first

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to override your own handler, check to see if you've set one:

```
if signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT) in [signal.SIG_IGN, signal.SIG_DFL]:
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, hi)
```

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#signal.getsignal), is is possible that some superior process had already reassigned the handler from the default. If you don't want to override that, add `None` to the list of signals.

The obvious wrapper for `signal.signal(..., signal.SIG_IGN)` would be a `not in` test.

**added in response to comment**

Chaining signal handlers is not often done because signals are so granular. If I really wanted to do this, I'd follow the model of [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) and register functions to be called by your handler.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the same as it would be done in C:

```
sig_hand_prev = None

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
  ...
  signal.signal(signum, sig_hand_prev)
  os.kill(os.getpid(), signum)

def install_handler(signum):
  global sig_hand_prev
  sig_hand_prev = signal.signal(signum, signal_handler)
```

The key idea here is that you save only the previous handler and raise it again when you finished your stuff. In this way the signal handling is a single linked list OOB.